# How can i make the pulse at V2 shift by 180 degrees in order to make it a negative 7.2 symbol for H bridge motor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, diodes, motor, h-bridge

[image]

This is the circuit I built in Lt spice. The NMOSFETS I downloaded online  have 1,2,3 automatically i cant change the label. 1= drain, 2 = gate, 3= source.

This is the result i get
[image]

However i need to get a reuslt similar to the image attached below but instead of 15v it needs to be plus and minus 7.2V. What changes can i make to my circuit to achieve this.
[image]

Comment: Yes sorry i made a typo yes i need it to be 180 degrees in order for V1 to be -7.2

Comment: Does your drawing package have proper transistor symbols? It would be a lot more obvious what's going on if you could use them. You could tighten up the schematic a lot to make the scale larger.

Comment: I downloaded the spice file for the mosfets online they automatically came with those symbols i cant change them. 1= drain 2 = gate 3 = source

Comment: 180 degrees is much easier than 90, simply invert the drive waveform.

Comment: Your schematic is impossible to read, not only because of those awful symbols, but beause of the way you placed them. And there's no explanation about `U1` and `U2`, which means nobody can tell whether the sources are floating or not. As @Transistor points out, use the builtin symbols for the NMOS and PMOS, `Ctrl+RClick` on them, change the prefixes from `MN` to `X` (same for `MP`), then rename them to have the same names as in your schematic. Last step: add `.lib /path/to/subcrcuit.sub` to the schematic (the correct path to the library/subcircuit/etc).